# SPFx - How do I know which version of node, gulp and yo to use?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, spfx-tooling

I see that certain versions of node, gulp etc. are incompatible with each other.

How do I know which versions are compatible with which?

Comment: C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution>gulp -v
[13:06:28] CLI version 3.9.1
[13:06:28] Local version 3.9.1

C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution>node -v
v10.13.0

C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution>gulp serve
Build target: DEBUG
[13:08:14] Using gulpfile C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution\gulpfile.js
[13:08:14] Task 'serve' is not in your gulpfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Node.js v12+ or higher, you must use Gulp v4+.

If you're using a version of Node.js lower than v12, you must use Gulp v3.

**Documentation**: [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Comment: Hi Ganesh I have done "npm install -g gulp@latest" and when I check "gulp --version" it says
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1

Comment: After I did the install of gulp latest it said ... gulp@4.0.2

Comment: Do I need to run a command to make it use the 4.0.2 version of gulp?

Comment: C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution>gulp -v [13:06:28] CLI version 3.9.1 [13:06:28] Local version 3.9.1 C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution>node -v v10.13.0 C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution>gulp serve Build target: DEBUG [13:08:14] Using gulpfile C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution\gulpfile.js [13:08:14] Task 'serve' is not in your gulpfile

Comment: Check gulp version in `package.json` file in solution.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh gulp is 3.9.1 in package.json. When I try to do gulp bundle --ship I get numerous ... Error - [tsc] src/webparts/basicList/BasicListWebPart.ts(457,17): error TS2416: Property 'dataVersion' in type 'BasicListWebPart' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseClientSideWebPart<IBasicListWebPartProps>'.

Answer (score 2):

Pete,

If you're planning on building a new solution, I'd say that Ganesh's answer is the right one; use the latest version of SPFx and Node + Gulp as per the documentation.

However, if you're trying to work with an older version of an SPFx solution, or if you're testing out a sample from https://aka.ms/spfx-webparts, you may want to refer to the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility), which lists which version of SPFx is compatible with which version of Node, Gulp, etc.

The short URL is: https://aka.ms/spfx-matrix

Finally, if you know that you'll need to switch between versions of Node (because, maybe, you're managing multiple solutions with different versions of SPFx), I'd suggest using NVM (I use [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)).

If you haven't looked into it, I'd recommend attending the [Sharing is Caring sessions](https://pnp.github.io/sharing-is-caring/), which are free sessions covering topics such as configuring your workstation, using NVM, etc.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks. I did npm install -g gulp@latest --global which tells me ... + gulp@4.0.2
updated 1 package in 12.317s
But when I do ...
C:\work\SPO\webparts\solution>gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1

Comment: @hugo Comp matrix is great resource. Thank you. HOwever, i dont see it mentiones Gulp version for each SPFX version? Does it matter? or latest gulp cli should work against all spfx?

Comment: That's a great point, @rohit. The version of Gulp depends on the version of Node -- which is controlled by the SPFx versions. Lemme see if I can update the matrix.

Comment: umm ok... Somehow, using NVM when I switch to Old node version and execute npm install gulp yo . It always installs latest gulp, though Node is old, unless we pass gulp version parameter.